# Prove $||u_{1} + u_{2} + \cdots + u_{n}||^{2} = ||u_{1}||^{2} + ||u_{2}||^{2} |\cdots+||u_{n}||^{2}$ if pairwise orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Let $u_{1},u_{2},u_{3}....u_{n}$ be orthogonal vectors in $\mathbb R^{n}$. Prove
>
> (ii)$\bf ||u_{1} + u_{2} + u_{3} + ... + u_{n}||^{2} = ||u_{1}||^{2} +
>  ||u_{2}||^{2} +||u_{3}||^{2} + ...+||u_{n}||^{2}$

My attempt:

I will try induction here

for $n = 2$, We have $$\bf ||u_{1} + u_{2}||^{2} = \Biggl(\sqrt{u_{1}^2 + 2u_{1}u_{2} + u_{2}^2 }\Biggl)^{2} = u_{1}^2 + \underbrace{2u_{1}u_{2}}_{= 0} + u_{2}^2 = ||u_{1}||^2 + ||u_{2}||^2 $$

Now suppose it is true for $n=k$, i.e

$$\bf ||u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k}||^{2} = \Bigl(u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k}\Bigr)^{2}=||u_{1}||^{2} + ||u_{2}||^{2} + ... + ||u_{k}||^{2}$$

Now we need to prove equality for $n = k+1$

$$\begin {align} \bf ||u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k} + u_{k+1}||^{2} = ||\Bigl(u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k}\Bigr) + u_{k+1}||^{2} =\end {align}\\
= \Biggl(\sqrt{\Bigl( \bf u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k}\Bigr)^{2} + 2u_{k+1}\Bigr( \bf u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k}\Bigr) + u_{k+1}^{2}}\Biggl)^{2}= \\
= \Bigl( \bf u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k}\Bigr)^{2} + 2\underbrace{\Bigr( \bf u_{1}u_{k+1} + u_{2}u_{k+1} + ... + u_{k}u_{k+1}\Bigr)}_{=0} + u_{k+1}^{2} = \\= \Bigl( \bf u_{1} + u_{2} + ... + u_{k}\Bigr)^{2} + u_{k+1}^{2} =\\
=||u_{1}||^{2} + ||u_{2}||^{2} + ... + ||u_{k}||^{2} + u_{k+1}^{2} =\\
=||u_{1}||^{2} + ||u_{2}||^{2} + ... + ||u_{k}||^{2} + ||u_{k+1}||^{2} $$

$\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Looks fine, what reason make you be unsure about your proof?

Comment: @chemist I am new to proofs, hence I just want to make sure that I haven't missed anything.

Comment: @Nelver I see, so the proof is full, very well written!